# PHP - Kill process kills server instead of background script

Tags: php, daemon

Im doing a process manager in PHP (Running XAMPP)

My task at hand = Have a multiple continuous process running(the managers), and depending on different variables fire of a new script. When initialized I get a process ID by using

```
$pid = getmypid();
```

I can then terminate the process by using

```
$kill = function($pid){ return stripos(php_uname('s'), 'win')>-1 
                    ? exec("taskkill /F /PID $pid") : exec("kill -9 $pid");
};

echo $kill($processid);
```

But this $kill now kills the server instead of the background process, why is that so?

I can see that the server runs on the same PID from looking at the error_log, which is why i suspect that to be the case, but what differentiates a new script from all the other scripts, so i can kill 1 of 6 managers?

Error_log also displays alongside PID its TID, what does TID refer to? (Could not find any documentation regarding TID)

Example:

```
[Mon Dec 18 19:01:18.885472 2017] [:error] [pid 17132:tid 1988] [client ::1:26218]
```

So in short:

- Is my assumption correct that as server is having the same PID being the reason the server dies and restarts?
- If that assumption is correct, how do i differentiate between scripts and kill them? TID?

Comment: Through the web browser, the script runs through the web server. Killing the server kills the whole process. As far as I know, there's no way to differentiate what is running and killing the specific request. If it was a command line script, that would be another matter.

Comment: XAMPP apparently runs the PHP script as a thread inside a single server process, rather than as a separate process.

Comment: Don't make long-running PHP processes from within Apache, especially if you're using mod_php. Stand up a proper, independent daemon process.